# MVC 3 DropDownListFor and the wrong value error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a problem with my code snippet inside the MVC 3 with Razor syntax. In my DB table (MySQL), I have a colum (FK) `LanguageID [int]`. Then, in that View, I want to assign to that column to the DropDownList with the languages list that I generate on the fly:

```
     List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

     list.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = tableRow.ID.ToString()
                        ,
                        Text = "language"
                    }
```

Then, in the View, I connects that list to the Language property:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
                 model => model.Language, 
                 new SelectList(ViewData["LanguageList"] as List<SelectListItem>,
                "Value", "Text")
                    )
```

but, when I post the data to the server, it returns with the error result `"The value '353' is invalid."` where the `353` is the Language ID from the DB. What am I doing wrong ?

Edit
Whle debugging, I've noticed the error message within the ModelState: `"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'FavorytaWeb.Models.BookLanguage' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."`

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to post the code that is called (form Controller/Action)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Language, 
    ...
)
```

with:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Language.LanguageID, 
    ...
)
```

You cannot bind the value `353` to a complex type which is what `model.Language` represents. It just doesn't make sense. You can bind it only to scalar properties.

Comment: obviously it worked, but I'm wondering, in that case the compiler 'connects' the LanguageID with the "Value" ?

Comment: @Tony, the compiler connects nothing. What the compiler does is to compile your C# code into MSIL. Then you run your code. Your code happens to be an ASP.NET MVC application. So you have a view which is posting some data to a controller action which takes as argument your view model. So the default model binder kicks in and attempts to bind the request values to this model.